# AJAX to  post values without using any jquery file

Tags: php, ajax

I want to post the field values entered in this code to the page ajaxpost.php using Ajax and then do some operations there. What would be code required to be written in ajaxpost.php. Also woithout using any js file/jquery
Here is the code of page in which fields are entered, I would like to know what would be the code to be written in ajaxpost.php

```
                 <html>
         <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadXMLDoc()
    {
       var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
     else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
            }
             var zz=document.f1.dd.value;   //alert(zz);
            var qq= document.f1.cc.value;
         xmlhttp.open("POST","ajaxpost.php",true);
           xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           xmlhttp.send("dd=zz&cc=qq");
     }
          </script>
        </head>
       <body>

     <h2>AJAX</h2>
  <form name="f1">
         <input type="text" name="dd">
        <input type="text" name="cc">
         <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
         <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </form>
        </body>
           </html>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow - you DON'T want to use JavaScript, but you DO want to use AJAX. You realize the "J" in AJAX stands for JavaScript? Do you mean that you want AJAX-like functionality, but without using JavaScript?

Comment: What are the operations you are trying to do? You can access the data in ajaxpost.php just like you would in a normal PHP page. $_POST['dd'], etc.

Comment: sorry 4 wrong title i changed title now, i know we require javascript , ok but i mean no need of any extra jquery files.

Comment: but when i use it i get result as zz @Jordan,  not the posted field value

Comment: operations are just to mail the posted values and then return back a "Hello Message"

Comment: JUST NEED TO USE LIKE THIS IT WORKS xmlhttp.send("fname="+zz+"&ccz="+qq);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for bare bones php and ajax for which there are tons of tutorials such as this [one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp), which is quite close to what you are looking for.